# How do I assign variables depending on the input? C++

Tags: c++

Currently working on something and I think I have 95% of it figured out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char vehicle, car, truck, bus;
double cost;
int hoursParked;
int main()
{
    cout << "Do you have a car, truck, or bus?" << endl << "c = car, t = truck, 
    b = bus" << endl;
    cin >> vehicle;
    if (cin == c) {
        vehicle = car;
    }
    cout << endl << "How long were you parked?" << endl;
    cin >> hoursParked;

    if (vehicle == car) {
        if (hoursParked <= 2) {
            cost = 1.25 * hoursParked;
        }
        else {
            cost = 1.25 * hoursParked;
            cost = 1.50 * (hoursParked - 2) + cost;
        }
    }

    cout << "Here is your receipt " << 1.25 * cost << endl;


}
```

This is just the beginning and I still have to add the bus and truck, but the problem I'm having is trying to figure out how to assign a variable depending on their input. How do I assign their vehicle to a car if they enter c, or if they enter t how do I assign that to be a truck?

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` when all you are trying to say is `'\n'` (or `"...\n..."`). If you really want to flush the stream then be explicit and use `std::flush`. Also, don't use global variables if you don't really, really have to.

Comment: Handy formatting trick: After pasting in your code, select it and either click the `{}` button above the editor window or press CTRL+K. This indents the entire selection 4 spaces and preserves your programs original indentation when displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things with your implementation that could use some help.

First, it looks like you're mixing up variable names with character constants:

```
int var = 'c'; // variable holding the character 'c'
```

so when you take a character as input, as in `cin >> vehicle;`, you want to compare that with 'c' for car, 'b' for bus etc.

```
char vehicle;
cin >> vehicle;
if (vehicle == 'c') { 
  //...
```

later you compare vehicle with car `if (vehicle == car) {` again here you're comparing the value of a variable named vehicle (which should be 'c', 'b', or 't') with a variable car, whose contents could be anything (likely zero).

Here's a quick rewrite to show you an example of one way to approach this, there are many others but I hope it helps you get started:

```
int main()
{
  double cost;
  int hoursParked;
  char choice;
  cout << "Do you have a car, truck, or bus?" << endl << "c = car, t = truck, b = bus" << endl;
  cin >> choice;
  bool isCar;
  switch (choice) {
  case 'c':
    isCar = true;
    break;
  case 't':
  case 'b':
    isCar = false;
    break;
  default:
    cerr << "invalid vehicle type: " << choice << "\n";
    return 1;
  };

  cout << endl << "How long were you parked?" << endl;
  cin >> hoursParked;

  if (isCar) {
    if (hoursParked <= 2) {
      cost = 1.25 * hoursParked;
    }
    else {
      cost = 1.25 * hoursParked;
      cost = 1.50 * (hoursParked - 2) + cost;
    }
  }
  cout << "Here is your receipt " << 1.25 * cost << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Do you have a car, truck, or bus?\nc = car, t = truck, b = bus\n";
    char vehicle; // declare your variables where they are used.
    cin >> vehicle; // let the user input a character we can evaluate later

    cout << "\nHow long were you parked?\n";
    int hoursParked;
    cin >> hoursParked;

    double cost;
    switch (vehicle) // evaluate the variable vehicle and switch upon its value
    {
    case 'c': // user input the letter 'c'
        if (hoursParked <= 2) {
            cost = 1.25 * hoursParked;
        }
        else {
            cost = 1.25 * hoursParked;
            cost = 1.50 * (hoursParked - 2) + cost;
        }
        break; // exit the switch. if there were no break execution would continue with case 't'

    case 't':
        // ... add your calculations for a truck
        break;

    case 'b':
        // ... add your calculations for a bus
        break;
    }

    cout << "Here is your receipt " << 1.25 * cost << '\n';
}
```